# Huawei Android phones not rejoining network ("saved, secured…")

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I am using Huawei Y6 Pro ,Model:TIT-U02, with android Lollipop 5.1 and two of my friends have the same device entirely and we all have the same problem.

When I restart my device, turn off the WiFi or even get out of my WiFi Network range accidentally, it shows in WiFi Settings under the name of the network " saved, secured with WPA/WPA2 " and when I try to connect to it, it shows " Authentication Error " and never connects. That always happens every time with no exceptions whether in my device or in my friends devices. That really annoys me because I don't spend a lot of time in the same place.

Does anyone have an experienced or useful method to solve this problem? I will be grateful if he helps me.

Regards to all!

Comment: So how do you ever successfully join a Wi-Fi network if rebooting, turning Wi-Fi off and on, and going out of range and coming back in range doesn’t help?

Comment: I have to forget the network and input the WiFi password again

Comment: Another related question came in today: https://superuser.com/questions/1245537/wifi-not-working-on-smartphone-saved-secured