# WIFI not working on smartphone | Saved Secured

Tags: wireless-networking, android, smartphone

My first post here (yay, thanks).
So basically, my Huawei 4C phone wifi stopped working out of the blue and it's the third week now (kinda frustrating being an IT and I can't fix it myself lol).
-by the way, it's android version is 4.4.2

So I did the following already:

- restart phone
  -factory reset (many times already)
  -checked if bluetooth and mobile is working (works)
  -tried to connect my phone on different wifi (office, neighbor's wifi, not 
  working) still showing saved or saved secured.

My router at home is just a simple one:

-Linksys with dhcp enabled: x.x.x.40 to x.x.x.130,
 -no mac filtering,
 -only less than 10 devices connects at a time and all works except my phone,
 -802.11 b/g/n or mixed mode,
 -tried to use wpa, static ip on my phone wifi, not working.

I even tried to reset my router but it didn't help.

So any ideas to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There was a similar question here yesterday. The (awful) workaround is to forget the network and rejoin it each time this happens.

Comment: Hi Spiff, thanks for the fast response. I did that s well, forget the network, but still it didn't work

Comment: Well, you might want to keep an eye on this one anyway: https://superuser.com/questions/1245240/huawei-android-phones-not-rejoining-network-saved-secured

Comment: Hmmm, seems like there is really no solution here :)